# Apache Camel CXF difficulty calling an RPC/Encoded WSDL when updating list of elements

Tags: apache-camel, wsdl, cxf, soap-client, camel-cxf

While not officially supported, with a few minor modifications to the WSDL I was able to successfully generate CXF Objects for the WSDL and get Camel CXF to talk to an RPC/Encoded WSDL endpoint.  The code is incredibly simple and most request/responses work without issue except for attempting to send updates of a list of elements.  Here is what the service expects:

`<elements arrayType="UpdateElement">`

VS here is what is being sent:

`<elements>`

I need to add the arrayType into the outgoing message.  I looked into a number of ways of doing this:

1) An interceptor right before the SOAP message is sent by CXF then use XPath to add the element but I was not clear how to accomplish this using Apache Camel + Camel CXF.  How to retrieve the CXF client from the Camel Context?

`MyService client = ???`

2) Fix it via WSDL?  Is it possible to add this element to the WSDL so it is generated as a part of the CXF Objects?  It is defined like this presently:

`<message name="wsdlElementRequest">
  <part name="elements" type="tns:UpdateElements" /></message>`

'message' and 'part' come from http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever stumbles on this with a similar issue, I figured it out myself.  I was able to retrieve the CxfEndpoint via CamelContext:

```
camelContext.getEndpoint(endpointUrl, CxfEndpoint.class);
```

Then I was able to add the interceptor I created:

```
public class MyCxfInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<SoapMessage> {
...
```

Using the CxfEndpoint methods:

```
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(new MyCxfInterceptor());
```

In my interceptor I also incorporated another interceptor, SAAJOutInterceptor, that converts the SOAP into an easy to work with object:

```
private List<PhaseInterceptor<? extends Message>> extras = new ArrayList<>(1);

public MyCxfInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.USER_PROTOCOL);
    extras.add(new SAAJOutInterceptor());
}

public Collection<PhaseInterceptor<? extends Message>> getAdditionalInterceptors() {
    return extras;
}
```

The easy to work with SOAP message:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage soapMessage) throws Fault {
    SOAPMessage msg = soapMessage.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);

    try {
        SOAPBody soapBody = msg.getSOAPBody();
```

Then it was a simple matter of using XPATH to make the correction to the outgoing SOAP message.

```
private XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
...
NodeList nodeList = soapBody.getElementsByTagName("tagName");
for (int x = 0; x < nodeList.getLength(); x++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(x);
    ((Element) node).setAttribute("missingAttributeName", "missingAttributeValue");
}
```

I hope this helps anyone working with challenging SOAP services!

Credit to the blog which played a big part in enabling me to implement this solution: https://xceptionale.wordpress.com/2016/06/26/message-interceptor-to-modify-outbound-soap-request/